# C# and Text file into a typed dataset

Tags: c#, .net, strongly-typed-dataset

Is there any way to load a text file (edi, efi file) into a typed dataset?  I thought you could do this using linq but have yet to figure how.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean, "convert"? Does the dataset already exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a driver/provider which will process the file type (an ODBC or an OLEDB one), you should be able to call the Fill method on your typed dataset passing the appropriate command to it which will parse the data from the file and populate your typed data set.